# A linearly ordered set $P$ has a countable dense subset, then $|P|\le 2^N$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a question on the book, "Introduction to Set Theory", by Karel Hrbacek and Thomas Jech, 101.p.

> If a linearly ordered set $P$ has a countable dense subset, then $|P|\le 2^N$

Clearly, $N \le P$, but I cannot go any further. Let $D$ the given subset, then $D$={$d_i$|$i \in N$} since D is countable. I think I need to use some theorems related to structure isomorphism, but professor doesn't cover it so I'm not sure what I should do now. Any hints or full answer would be very thankful.

Comment: I suppose $|P|$ is the cardinality of $P$, and I guess $N$ is the set of natural numbers. Is $2^N$ the set of all subsets of $N$? In the inequality $|P|\le2^N$, you seem to have a **number** on the left and a **set** on the right. Should't they both be numbers? Do you mean $|2^N|$ on the right side?>

Comment: Oh yes, I think I should have written that way. But as far as I know (I'm just a beginner in set theory) natural numbers and the set itself are the cardinalities each for a finite set and a countable set, so I thought it's allowable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** For each $p\in P$ let $I_p=\{i:d_i\lt p\}$. The map $p\mapsto I_p$ may not be one-to-one, but it's at most two-to-one, and so the number of points in $P$ is at most twice the number of subsets of $N$.

Comment: I tried to make an infinite sequence for given $p$ as follows: if $d_i$ is in $I_p$, $a(i)=1$, otherwise, $a(i)=0$. But if there is an upperbound for D which is not in D, then there are infinitely many upperbounds not in D(I guess, since the set is dense), which means for those p the sequence would be the same <1, 1, 1, ...>. In this case it's not even one-to-one or two-to-one. Maybe I've got a wrong way?

Comment: If there are infinitely meny upper bounds for $D$, then $D$ is **not** dense. What is the exact definition of "dense subset of a linearly ordered set" that you are working with?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a question: my professor passed that part so I didn't have enough time to cover it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Dense is used in the sense of an order. So $D$ being dense means for $x,y \in D$ where $x < y$, there is a $z \in D$ such that $x < z < y$.

Comment: I've been thinking about this problem and I don't think this hint works at all. As a counter example let $P = [0,3] \subseteq \mathscr{R}$ and let $D = \{q \in \mathscr{Q} \,|\, q \in [0,1) \cup (2,3]\}$ all with the usual order. I believe that $Q$ is indeed is a countable dense subset of $P$ and yet any $p \in [1,2] \subseteq P$ maps to the same $I_p$ as defined above. Hence this mapping is nowhere near injective since an uncountable number of points map to the same set!

Comment: @kyp4 What makes you think $D$ is dense in $P$?

Comment: @bof The question says that $D$ is a dense subset of $P$. This is actually ambiguous as it's not clear whether $D$ is dense with respect to $P$ or only with respect to itself. I emailed Dr. Jech about this to clarify but he did not respond. In my counter example above I meant that $D$ is dense with respect to itself. I was able to prove this assuming it is dense in $P$ but unable to if it is merely dense with respect to itself. It looks like HagenvonEitzen does show this in the latter case in his answer. However, see my comment there.

Comment: @kyp4 "$D$ is a dense subset of $P$" means that $D$ is dense with respect to $P$. That's what "dense subset of $P$" always means. For the other notion, there is the term "dense-in-itself" but it would be nonsense in the context of this problem: if an ordered set contains a countable subset which is dense-in-itself, then **any larger ordered set** would have the same property, so you wouldn't be able to get any upper bound for the size of $P$ from that.

Comment: @bof Yes this makes perfect sense! It is a bit of a relief too since I was able to prove it when $D$ is dense with respect to $P$ but not if it were the other case, and you basically just proved that the conclusion is not necessarily true in the other case.

Comment: Isn't the map in fact one-to-one by the denseness?

Comment: @izimath Suppose $P=[0,\pi]\cup[4,5]$. Then $D=P\cap\mathbb Q$ is a dense subset of $P$. Note that $\{d\in D:d\lt\pi\}=\{d\in D:d\lt4$.

Comment: @izimath Thanks for correcting my silly typo.

Comment: So the possibility of successor in $P$ makes two-to-one possible. By the way, is the notion " dense subset" defined as: for $ p_1 ,p_2 \in P$,  $\textbf{if} '(p_1,p_2)  \neq \emptyset $, the there exist some element of the subset in $(p_1,p_2)$?

Comment: Then I think the map can also be many-to-one if there are some finitely many successors in a row in $P$.

Comment: @izimath How so? Suppose $p\lt q\lt r$ and $I_p=I_q=I_r$. Then $(p,r)\ne\emptyset$, so there is some element $d_i\in D\cap(p,r)$. Then $i\in I_r$ but $i\notin I_p$, contradicting $I_p=I_r$.

Comment: I just figure that out too. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For each $p\in P$ there exists a sequence $(d_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of elements in $D$ such that $d_n\to p$. Since $D$ is countable, there are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ sequences (even ignoring convergence) - just like there are only $2^{\aleph_0}$ sequences of natural or rational numbers.

Comment: I've understood that there are only $2^N$ sequences, but I couldn't understand the first sentence. Does it mean that D has a complete linearly ordered set P unique up to isomorphism? I haven't studied that part that much so I am just wondering where the given conditions have been applied.

Comment: Don't you need at least a metric space to have a convergent sequence? Nobody ever said that $P$ had any kind of metric.

Comment: @kyp4 I need topology for convergence, not necessarily a metric. And any ordered set can be equipped with the order topology. Spelled out, we can say that $a_n\to a$ if $b<a$ implies $b<a_n$ for almost all $n$ and $b>a$ implies $b>a_n$ for almost all $n$. The important point is that a sequence cannot converge to more than one limt

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen This is interesting and a nice proof; I am not familiar with order topologies yet. Because of this, however, I'm confident that this is not a proof that is intended by the author as these are not covered in the book, but this certainly does not invalidate this approach.