# Linearly ordered Set with countably dense subset.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

"If a linearly ordered set $P$ has a countable dense subset $D$, then
$|P|\le2^N$"

1) Is the set $D$ dense in $P$ ?

2) I know there is another link regarding the same question but I do not see how      the solutions provided form an injection from $P$ to $2^N$(or $P(N)$ or R or ...).

[A linearly ordered set $P$ has a countable dense subset, then $|P|\le 2^N$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798952/a-linearly-ordered-set-p-has-a-countable-dense-subset-then-p-le-2n)

3) My initial solution was to consider the sets $\forall p\in P$ $S_p = \{x\in D
 | x < p\}$ but I still can't get any useful injection.

Any hints or suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p\ne q$ then $S_p\ne S_q$.

We may assume wlog. that $p<q$. Then there exists $x\in D$ with $p<x<q$. But that means $x\in S_q$ and $x\notin S_p$.

Comment: Hi so in this case the set D is dense in P?

Comment: @JhonDeo Yes. If youe wanted to interprete "has a countable dense subset $D$" as "has a countable subset $D$ such that induced order on $D$ is a dense order", then the statement of cause becomes false. Just consider any very large ordered set $P_0$ and let $P$ be the disjoint union of $P_0$ and $D:=\Bbb Q$ (with declaring $x<y$ for $x\in P_0$, $y\in \Bbb Q$).